# Beam Create file with key name and write values from it to file

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have beam pipeline in Java. Which creates KV pairs out of GroupbyKey. I want to write the output to folder based on key. Can you please suggest

```java
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<String>>> sucessResponsepCollection = pipeline.apply("Extract Success response string for Model " + model, ParDo.of(new ExtractSuccessResponseFn()))
                        .apply(GroupByKey.create());

 // how to write separate avro file each key with multiple values.

 sucessResponsepCollection.apply(AvroIO.writeGenericRecords(schemaFile)
                                    .withOutputFilenames( )
                                    .to(**KEY** + "/part")
                                    .withWindowedWrites()
                                    .withNumShards(options.getNumberShards() == null ? 0 : options.getNumberShards())
                                    .withSuffix(AVRO_FILENAME_SUFFIX)));
```

Answer (score 3):

The [AvroIO class documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.42.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html) has a section "Writing data to multiple destinations" that addresses this. You define an implementation of `DynamicAvroDestinations` and pass an instance of that class as the argument to `.to`.

The example from the docs is:

```
 // This is the user class that controls dynamic destinations for this avro write. The input to
 // AvroIO.Write will be UserEvent, and we will be writing GenericRecords to the file (in order
 // to have dynamic schemas). Everything is per userid, so we define a dynamic destination type
 // of Integer.
 class UserDynamicAvroDestinations
     extends DynamicAvroDestinations<UserEvent, Integer, GenericRecord> {
   private final PCollectionView<Map<Integer, String>> userToSchemaMap;
   public UserDynamicAvroDestinations( PCollectionView<Map<Integer, String>> userToSchemaMap) {
     this.userToSchemaMap = userToSchemaMap;
   }
   public GenericRecord formatRecord(UserEvent record) {
     return formatUserRecord(record, getSchema(record.getUserId()));
   }
   public Schema getSchema(Integer userId) {
     return new Schema.Parser().parse(sideInput(userToSchemaMap).get(userId));
   }
   public Integer getDestination(UserEvent record) {
     return record.getUserId();
   }
   public Integer getDefaultDestination() {
     return 0;
   }
   public FilenamePolicy getFilenamePolicy(Integer userId) {
     return DefaultFilenamePolicy.fromParams(new Params().withBaseFilename(baseDir + "/user-"
     + userId + "/events"));
   }
   public List<PCollectionView<?>> getSideInputs() {
     return ImmutableList.<PCollectionView<?>>of(userToSchemaMap);
   }
 }
 PCollection<UserEvents> events = ...;
 PCollectionView<Map<Integer, String>> userToSchemaMap = events.apply(
     "ComputePerUserSchemas", new ComputePerUserSchemas());
 events.apply("WriteAvros", AvroIO.<Integer>writeCustomTypeToGenericRecords()
     .to(new UserDynamicAvroDestinations(userToSchemaMap)));
```

In your case, the destination would of type `String` (matching your key that you want to inject) and you would define the full path with the key injected via your implementation of `getFilenamePolicy`.